# Navigation in Power BI

Tags: microsoft-metro, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset with personid, name, email, address. How to navigate records in Power bi, by clicking the next or previous button,(if something like this is available) we can see the details of the coming record or the last record. I tried slicer for person id to display the respective content in the table format for the person id selected but what to do if I want to use next and previous option and not the slicer option?

Comment: can you post some screen shots of your model and maybe your desired output?

Comment: I solved the problem by using bookmark and drill down options. Thank you for the reply.